# The coproduct of any indexed collection of quasicategories is a quasicategory.

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, simplicial-stuff

I'm reading the following document: [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/quasicats.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Erezk/quasicats.pdf)

The proposition I'm having trouble with is the following: The coproduct of any indexed collection of quasicategories is a quasicategory. (6.7 in the document)

To prove this proposition, the author uses the following information.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Given this information, the proof goes as follows:

[image]

I understand everything upto "The proof is now straightforward...". That is, I don't know how to use 6.12 and 6.11 to reach the conclusion.

At this point, I'm not even sure how contentedness would imply that inner horn filling condition is fulfilled.

Any help on understanding the proof would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ask Charles Rezk?

Comment: @JCAA Huh? That's a kind of odd suggestion, help with solving problems in published expository works, whether by living authors or no, is pretty much what MSE is all about. Many authors would be a bit slow to help random people from the Internet with standard exercises. Phil, while Eric's argument works great to follow Rezk's suggestions, if you try thinking about the claim from scratch I bet you'll be able to convince yourself it's pretty simple. There's really not much going on here--the $X_s$ don't interact at all in $X$.

Comment: @KevinArlin: What "Huh"? As far as I know Charles Rezk is alive and well. One can google his name and find his email address.

Comment: @JCAA You misunderstood me. Charles is a nice guy, but there's no particular reason to bug him over a question like this, which doesn't require anything like his level of expertise, when there are several folks here who have signaled we are actively interested in doing so. One doesn't generally email a textbook author as a first resort about the exercises in their book, and this is a textbook-type exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $h:\Lambda^n_j\to X$ is an inner horn, then the image of $h$ is connected, and thus is contained in some connected component of $X$, which is in turn contained in one of the $X_s$.  This means that $h$ actually factors through a map $h':\Lambda^n_j\to X_s$.  Since $X_s$ is a quasicategory, $h'$ can be extended to $g':\Delta^n\to X_s$.  Composing $g'$ with the inclusion $X_s\to X$ then gives an extension $g:\Delta^n\to X$ of $h$.